# Spring batch : Writing to 2 different databases

Tags: transactions, spring-batch

My Spring batch application uses 2 databases - Informix and Oracle.
I am reading from Oracle database ( and my spring batch tables are also in Oracle).

**Scenario 1:**
I need to write the data into both Informix and Oracle. What is the best practice to make sure the data is in sync between the tables in both databases ? 
(a) Use a CompositeItemwriter with XATransactionManager and write into both tables in 1 step ?
(b) Have 2 separate steps ; One step loads data into Oracle tables. Next step reads the oracle database and writes into infromix database.

**Scenario 2:**
In a few other steps in my job, I need to inactivate the records in the table in both the databases, from the ItemProcessor. For this scenario, I am using DAO and jdbTemplate for the updates.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a `CompositeItemWriter` in Scenario 2 as well? You'd be able to batch the updates (I assume they're updates) for better performance.

Comment: In scenario 2, I have to inactivate previously created records and insertnew records, if required. So I use the itemprocessor and jdbctemplate to update and then write new record in the itemwriter.

Comment: For Scenario 1: which is the better option :  a) Use a CompositeItemwriter with XATransactionManager and write into both tables in 1 step ?   OR  (b) Have 2 separate steps ; One step loads data into Oracle tables. Next step reads the oracle database and writes into infromix database.

Comment: Properly configuring (and testing) global transactions can be tough. As long as you are okay having your inserts to one DB slightly before the other, I'd break it into 2 steps. Your testing and restartability will both be significantly simplified. As for scenario 2, I would have your processor manipulate your objects in memory and then use a composite writer for both the update and insert. Again here, I would keep it simple by doing one step per DB